# Refreshing a hyperlink text

Tags: java, hyperlink, jcombobox

I got a JComboBox and a AppXHyperlink, both in separate classes. I'd like to set the hyperlink text with the selected item from the JComboBox (to know what I've selected). Is there an easy way for doing this? By using `actionPerformed` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold the reference of hyperlink in combobox, and change its text with action performed.
Or you can fireEvent about changing hyperlink that will be update in your hyperlink class by listener, look into pattern [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: Looks nice, I'll try it. Thanks.